# Can you have multiple tags with xml tag having CDATA section?

Tags: xml, cdata

I have an xml file that looks like this :

```
 <bookstore>  

 <book category="COOKING">  
   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  
   <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>  
   <year>2005</year>  
   <price>30.00</price>  
   <![CDATA[<<port>url=  https://localhost:8080<port>]]>
 </book>
```

I see that when this is processed, the entire  tag is considered as CDATA. Can you use other tags inside a tag having CDATA? I did not find any online samples that did this.

Comment: That would defeat the whole point of `CDATA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you seem to be unclear what a "tag" is. Given this:

```
<a><![CDATA[xyz]]></a>
```

there are two tags: a start tag `<a>` and an end tag `</a>`. The CDATA section is not "in" a tag, it is between two tags.

So when you say 'the entire tag is considered as CDATA' I think you mean 'the entire content between the tags is considered as CDATA'; and yes, that is correct. And when you say 'Can you use other tags inside a tag having CDATA?' I think you mean 'can you have tags inside a CDATA section?', and the answer is no: the only point of using a CDATA section is to prevent any angle brackets inside the section being recognized as markup.

Comment: Angle brackets and ampersands.

Comment: I think I would like to rephrase my question. I would like to know if my example above is valid xml. The book tag also has the title, author, year and price along with the CDATA section. Is that valid?

Comment: Yes, your example is well-formed. But you can find that out more easily and reliably by throwing it at an XML parser to see if it reports any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.

In your case `<<port>url=  https://localhost:8080<port>` will not be considered to be XML containing tags, but plain text.

If you'd like to have a port element containing a CDATA section you should modify your line to

`<port><![CDATA[url=  https://localhost:8080]]></port>`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [definition of a CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) all content between the opening `<![CDATA[` and closing `]]>` tag is considered text input and no processing is done on the information at all.

Now, once you extract it if you are forming valid XML within the CDATA section you could then process that document separately.

Comment: Mitchel, my question was, how the data/tags which are present along with a CDATA section in an XML are treated and NOT inside the CDATA section itself. IN my example, how are the tags, author, title etc treated?